# Android emulator multi-touch

Tags: android

According to the [Android documentation](http://tools.android.com/tips/hardware-emulation), it's possible to test multi-touch actions in the emulator using a companion app on a tethered device.  However, the documentation is pretty skimpy... I'm hoping someone can fill in the blanks here.

1. The documentation says that "when creating the AVD, make sure to add the hardware property Multi-touch screen support, and set it to true."  **How does one "add the hardware property Multi-touch screen support"?**  I don't see any such option in the AVD editor:

[image: AVD Editor]

2. The docs also say "Port forwarding is used again. This time the port is 1969".  **What do I do with that?**
3. Are there any other settings or tricks, not discussed by the docs, needed to get the app talking to the emulator?

Answer (score 3):

The document is a bit outdated. For example, now the forwarded port should be 1970 and only this one.

If you install the SDK Controller app, which is located in `$SDK/tools/apps/SdkController/`, you can see the correct instruction in that app.

1. To enable multi-touch support, you need to add `-screen multi-touch` in `emulator`'s parameter.
2. Only 1970 need to be forwarded. Run `adb forward tcp:1970 localabstract:android.sdk.controller` on your computer.
3. Yes! If you use a 64-bit emulator to run the image, you will find it not working :( It seems there is a bug in the emulator caused by alignment. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=29735

   To workaround this issue, you can use a 32-bit emulator or fixing it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Correct adding on the post above you need to run:

```
$ adb forward tcp:1970 localabstract:android.sdk.controller
```

(the latest release includes for both Multi-touch and Sensor emulation)

It's also been adviced that it is possible to fix the 32-bit error with the following:

In the *sdk-controller-socket.c* source file.

The problem can be solved on 64-bit builds by either:

1. On line 279, add `__attribute__((packed))` to the `SDKCtlMessage struct`, OR
2. On line 922, replace `memcpy(msg + 1, data, size);` with `memcpy(&(msg->msg_type) + 1, data, size);`

I haven't personally tried it but would be curious to find out if it works and the *SDKController* application over-all works cause I haven't managed to get past the "Waiting for Connection". Despite it does show "Emulator Connected" right when the emulator loads but stops right after that if I go back and even if I don't, no sensor or multi-touch goes through.